# Why boost does not create a thread in such case (C2248) and how to create it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, boost-thread

So I have code like:

```
using namespace boost::asio::ip;
using namespace std;

void request_response_loop(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket)
{
    http_request request(socket);
    http_response response;
    response.body = "<head></head><body><h1>It Rocks!</h1></body>";
    response.send(socket);
    socket.close();
    cout << "connection resolved." << endl;
}


void acceptor_loop(){
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    int m_nPort = 12345;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), m_nPort));
    cout << "Waiting for connection..." << endl;
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            tcp::socket socket(io_service);
            acceptor.accept(socket);
            cout << "connection accepted." << endl;
            boost::thread workerThread2(request_response_loop, socket); // here it does not compile because of C2248
        }
        catch(exception &e)
        {
            cerr << e.what() << endl; //"The parameter is incorrect" exception
        }
    }
}
int main()
{ 
    boost::thread workerThread(acceptor_loop);
    cin.get();
}
```

It gives me error:

```
Error   1   error C2248: boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable: "boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable"  boost\asio\basic_io_object.hpp  93
```

How to make it possible to run my request_response_loop function in another thread that one I use for socket accepting?

Comment: Never use references for parameters in your thread entry function. This is prone to the defects you see. Always use pointers or some smart pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Ben's answer, `boost::shared_ptr<>` is the usual mechanism here:

```
void request_response_loop(boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket)
{
    http_request request(*socket);
    http_response response;
    response.body = "<head></head><body><h1>It Rocks!</h1></body>";
    response.send(*socket);
    socket->close();
    cout << "connection resolved." << endl;
}

void acceptor_loop()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    int m_nPort = 12345;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), m_nPort));
    cout << "Waiting for connection..." << endl;
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket =
                boost::make_shared<tcp::socket>(boost::ref(io_service));
            acceptor.accept(*socket);
            cout << "connection accepted." << endl;
            boost::thread workerThread2(request_response_loop, socket);
        }
        catch(exception &e)
        {
            cerr << e.what() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiler tells me that it can not turn ( error C2664: boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<Protocol>::basic_stream_socket(boost::asio::io_service &)) 'boost::asio::io_service *const ' into 'boost::asio::io_service &' \include\boost\smart_ptr\make_shared.hpp 1

Comment: my comment resolved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663076/shared-ptr-of-socket-creation-what-is-wrong

Comment: `auto_ptr` should work here, because it's a one-time handoff, not ongoing sharing, and `auto_ptr` is standard.  Also, is `boost::shared_ptr` thread-safe, or would you need synchronization around operations which modify the reference count?

Comment: @Ben Voigt : Yes, `boost::shared_ptr<>` is thread-safe. It uses CAS intrinsics when possible, and falls back to a mutex when not.

Answer (score 2):

Next time show the entire error message.

Your problem is that your thread procedure wants a reference to the socket, but the socket is a local variable.  The `acceptor_loop` function doesn't wait, so it will destroy the socket as soon as it goes out of scope.

You need to use dynamic or static lifetime, never automatic, for variables passed between threads.