# Shared_Ptr of socket creation - what is wrong?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, shared-ptr

So I try:

```
        boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket =
            boost::make_shared<tcp::socket>(io_service);
```

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657011/why-boost-does-not-create-a-thread-in-such-case-c2248-and-how-to-create-it/5657118#5657118). But It bring me an error:

Compiler tells me that it can not turn (

```
error C2664: 
boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<Protocol>::basic_stream_socket(
    boost::asio::io_­service &))
'boost::asio::io_service *const ' into 'boost::asio::io_service &'
\include\boost\smart_ptr\make_shared.hpp
```

What shall I do?

Comment: show us your io_service declaration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the `io_service` as a reference when using `make_shared`.

```
boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket =
            boost::make_shared<tcp::socket>(boost::ref(io_service));
```